# Delegates and Memory Leaks in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have a tableview(being IBOutlet) and tableviewController in my ViewController

what I do is

//.... allocation for tableviewController
self.tableview.delegate =  tableviewController;

//now this increases the retain count of tableviewController...

So in deallocation do I need to set the tableview delegate to nil...like

self.tableview.delegate = nil;
or 
self.tableview = nil; // is sufficient to make sure that the retain count of tableviewController get decreased by 1.

Answer (score 1):

The tableView already realeases its delegate in its dealloc method, so you should be ok without having to explicitly set the delegate to  nil.

Comment: No, the table view neither retains nor releases its delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The table view does not retain its delegate:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate
```

The reason is that retaining would likely cause a retain cycle. See [Avoiding retain cycles rule #3: "Connection" objects should not retain their target](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html).
To keep the delegate alive, you must maintain a reference to it yourself somewhere.